# Why wont my app save 2 values and then display them the next time the app is open?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I recently learnt about SharedPreferences and now I tried to put it in my code. I have 2 integer values called counter and counterPS. What I want to happen is that the app will save the values every 5 seconds and then when the app is completely closed and completely re opened (phone turned off and on again for example) I want the app to see if the values that were saved (if they even were) are bigger than 0, if so then set the current values to the old saved ones. However I set a number for the values inside the app and waited five seconds for it to save and when i restarted the app completely the values just came up as 0. Why is this and can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    SharedPreferences saving = getSharedPreferences("ShipData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saving.edit();

    int counter = saving.getInt("shipCounter", 0);
    int counterPS = saving.getInt("shipCounterPS", 0);

    if(mShip.getCounter() == 0) {
        if (counter > 0) {
            mShip.setCounter(counter);
            mShip.setCounterPerSec(counterPS);
        }
    }


    //Save values every 5 seconds Below
    new TimerClass(5000, 1000)
    {
        public void OnFinish()
        {
            editor.putInt("ShipCounter", mShip.getCounter());
            editor.putInt("ShipCounterPS", mShip.getCounterPerSec());
            editor.commit();
            this.start();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I would ask if your class TimerClass is tested. Also, keep in mind that `editor.commit();` returns true if saved successfully and false otherwise, you might want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

How about using handler ( the android way) instead of timer class? does it suit in your case ?

For more info:

http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

I am aware that the question was posted a while back. Just replying to it for similar future questions ... Thanks.